# Struts2 <s:select list=""> not working dynamically

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am using Struts2.

```
<s:iterator value="empReportFields" var="empReportField" 
    <s:select name="%{#empReportField.fieldName}" list="%{#empReportField.listName}" listKey="id" listValue="name" cssClass="search" headerValue="All" headerKey="All" />                                           

    <s:property value="#empReportField.listName" />
    // Here it is displaying proper list name                   
</s:iterator>
```

I am fetching out these data from my db. Now I am displaying specific list in select box (`<s:select list="<ListName>" />`) which is stored in column of my table (Database).

Normally it runs like.

```
<s:select name="emp" list="locationList" 
          listKey="id" listValue="name" 
          headerValue="All" headerKey="All" />
```

It will work well.

But I find simple select box with no list value in it. So what is the actual problem??

In short I want to call list dynamically.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Is there an action property named `locationList` with (a) a public getter, and (b) data in it?

Comment: can we have little more clarity on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: There is action which create List of locationList... But now I have stored this list name in my db and fetching out and i want tot display dynamically it means according to iterator

Comment: Post your action code.

Answer (score 1):

The s:select tag itslef has a list attribute where you can directly give the name of the list (in action class) you want to fill the dropdown with. You do not need an iterator for packing values into s:select dropdown.

Try this:

```
<s:select label="Select from here" 
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select"
        list="listNameHere" 
        name="feildNameHere" />
```

Here 'listNameHere' is the list in action layer and the 'feildNameHere' is a instance variable in action class which recieves the value selected by the user.

Comment: AFAICT the OP is aware of this.

Comment: It simplay works fine. NOw I have stored list name in db and i fethed that name and call it dyanamically. It means in, <s:select list =""> has value like "locationList" (from DB) but not displaying list value. it simply blank. It means i stored more than one listName in db and filling all the select box dynamically. But it just display name only instead on its list value.

Comment: ok, so what i understand is that, you are fetching the name of list from your DB so that the s:select can refer to different lists at different times? Also you have put the s:select in  iterator, that means that you would be having multiple s:select dropdowns?

Comment: can you also post the HTML source generated for the s:select dropdown ?

Comment: yes you are ri8. If I fetch listName from db then it not works. it displaying name of list but not rendered as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to how I understand the question you want to load `<s:select list` dynamically according to the iterator value.

If so just use the `<s:select list` like this `<s:select list="#empReportField.listName"`.

Where `<s:iterator value="empReportFields"` is a list and inside that list another list or map named `listName`.